# How to launch web application without any browser

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, software-distribution

I have ASP.NET MVC web application which is running on the local network. The application is using bootstrap and crystal reports. What is the best launcher to launch this application on local machines if I want to avoid any browser?

I was using chrome short cut and was opening it as a window before. In a recent update of Chrome (Version: 71), they have removed that option while creating a shortcut. I would be grateful if someone can suggest the best launcher which I can configure or use to use my ASP.NET MVC web application as local software.

Comment: What do you mean by "launch"? This question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I need to give user an icon on the desktop. So when he clicks my web application will not open in browser rather it will appear like a desktop application.

Comment: You could have an Electron app to load your web application. Perhaps this could be helpful. https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier